# Defining tablespace for local index in Oracle

Tags: oracle, indexing

When we generate scripts to create indexes for partitioned tables, we currently have something like this:

```
CREATE INDEX "SCHEMA"."INDEX_NAME" ON "SCHEMA"."TABLE_NAME" (
  "COLUMN_NAME"
)
LOCAL
(
  PARTITION "P1" TABLESPACE "INDEX_TABLESPACE_NAME",
  PARTITION "P2" TABLESPACE "INDEX_TABLESPACE_NAME",
  PARTITION "PMAX" TABLESPACE "INDEX_TABLESPACE_NAME"
);
```

We're thinking about changing this to:

```
CREATE INDEX "SCHEMA"."INDEX_NAME" ON "SCHEMA"."TABLE_NAME" (
  "COLUMN_NAME"
)
LOCAL;
```

In this case, how would I define the tablespace that the indexes should be placed in? All of the partitions for a table will go in the same tablespace, and all of the indexes for the table should go in one (different) tablespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I recall you just define a default tablespace for the index:

```
CREATE INDEX
  "SCHEMA"."INDEX_NAME"
ON
  "SCHEMA"."TABLE_NAME" (
    "COLUMN_NAME")
TABLESPACE
  MY_INDEX_TABLESPACE
LOCAL;
```

You know that there's no performance benefit to storing table and index segments in different tablespaces, right?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Yeah, we're just looking for ease of management.

Comment: then set the default tablespace at schema level and you'll never have to set the tablespace for a specific object again.

Comment: @haki William is specifying different tablespaces for table and index segment here though.

Comment: haven't noticed - then it's obviously irrelevant.